# Why is vertical-align:text-top; not working in CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to align some text to the top of a div. It seems that `vertical-align: text-top;` should do the trick, but it doesn't work. The other things that I have done, such as putting the divs into columns and displaying a dashed border (so I can see where the top of the div is) all work fine.

```
#header_p { 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header_selecttxt {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
#header_div_left { 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
    border: dashed;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#header_div_right { 
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: dashed;
}
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The vertical-align attribute is for inline elements only. It will have no effect on block level elements, like a div. Also text-top only moves the text to the top of the current font size. If you would like to vertically align an inline element to the top just use this.

```
vertical-align: top;
```

The paragraph tag is not outdated. Also, the vertical-align attribute applied to a span element may not display as intended in some mozilla browsers.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The text gets always aligned center-vertically :(

Comment: Fast forward 14 years... this `vertical-align: top;` rule was the missing key to keep my MaterializeCSS breadcrumb links inside their container. I nest an additional `div.content` to control side gutter width and override the element height, which put the text placing of the `a.breadcrumb` out of whack.

Answer (score 31):

`vertical-align` is only supposed to work on elements that are rendered as `inline`.  `<span>` is rendered as inline by default, but not all elements are.  The paragraph block element, `<p>`, is rendered as a block by default.  Table render types (e.g. `table-cell`) will allow you to use vertical-align as well.

Some browsers may allow you to use the `vertical-align` CSS property on items such as the paragraph block, but they are not supposed to.  Text denoted as a paragraph should be filled with written-language content or the mark-up is incorrect and should be using one of a number of other options instead.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 18):

something like

```
  position:relative;
  top:-5px;
```

just on the inline element itself works for me.
Have to play with the top to get it centered vertically...

Answer (score 7):

You could apply `position: relative;` to the div and then `position: absolute; top: 0;` to a paragraph or span inside of it containing the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contextual selectors and move the vertical-align there. This would work with the p tag, then. Take this snippet below as an example. Any p tags within your class will respect the vertical-align control:

```
#header_selecttxt {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#header_selecttxt p {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

You could also keep the vertical-align in both sections so that other, inline elements would use this.

Answer (score 1):

The all above not work for me, I have just checked this and its work :

> vertical-align: super;

```
 <div id="lbk_mng_rdooption" style="float: left;">
     <span class="bold" style="vertical-align: super;">View:</span>
 </div>
```

I know by padding or margin will work, but that is last choise I prefer.

Comment: Don't know why but `<span>` do better than `<p>` or `<h6>`

Answer (score 0):

PS.: I'm not a ux or frontend engineer

```
.make-it-valign-on-top {
    vertical-align: super;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<span class="make-it-valign-on-top">my text</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
position:absolute;
top:0px; 
margin:5px;
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can use margin-top: -50% to move the text all the way to the top of the div.

```
margin-top: -50%;
```

Answer (score -3):

The problem I had can't be made out from the info I have provided:

- I had the text enclosed in old school `<p>` tags.

I changed the `<p>` to `<span>` and it works fine.

Comment: <p> is certainly not old school, heaven forbid a website be made up of <div> and <span> exclusively.

Comment: I have limited web experience but whenever I try raw <div> and only using tables to display information, I find it quite hard to KEEP everything inside the 'wrapper' <div> for example. Rarely get that with tables, if something is in a cell it doesn't normally pop out!

Comment: The crucial difference is due to the use of a *block* tag `<p>` vs. an inline tag `<span>`.

Comment: Set display as inline-block then only your vertical align will work in  your case.