# HTML Content within table cell from a table-layout has different padding & margins when the content is changed from the other cell

Tags: html, css, layout, tablelayout

I have a fixed `table-layout` div parent with two horizontal `table-cell` children.

On the left cell, I just simply put in some text. However, when the right cell has a tall image, the text on the left cell is pined to the bottom no matter what html padding & margin styles I put in. When the right cell has some multi-line text, the text on the left cell is placed on top.

I want the text from the left cell to stay on top all the time. Where am I missing?

**html**

```
<div class="row-post">
  <div class="col-cell col-fixed" style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-cell pl-3">
    <img src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/001/295/524/cda.jpg" style="height:300px">
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row-post">
  <div class="col-cell col-fixed">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-cell pl-3">
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  <p>Some long text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.row-post {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.row-post .col-cell {
  display:table-cell;
}

.row-post .col-cell img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.col-fixed {
  width: 26px;
}
```

**js fiddle if you want to play around**

https://jsfiddle.net/f1zr6o93/

**js fiddle snip**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For table render types, you can use:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

on any "table cell".

[Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c13r658p/)

For reference, there's a fuller explanation of [when vertical align applies in this other SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924282/why-is-vertical-aligntext-top-not-working-in-css).