# Wrap text above, not below

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a CSS fix to wrap text above instead of below.

For example, how do achieve this:

[image: 1]

Not this:

[image: 2]

I have a set width to the div and though that fixing the div to the bottom may help, but it did not.

Comment: Hey, it would be nice if you provide a [minima reproduce example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924282/why-is-vertical-aligntext-top-not-working-in-css - you're possibly create a duplicate question

Comment: Thanks, I checked the other question, but it is not related to this particular thing.
Here is a reproduction: https://codepen.io/yellowF00D/pen/NWBqjKE

Answer (score 0):

You might use this:
`<div id="abc">WORN OUT: <br> DRESSED TO ASCEND FINALLY</div>`